# How can I both draw and fill a grid in a tree node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, grids

I would like to draw a 1x3 grid in the top tree node, then fill the two leftmost cells of the grid.

This is my code:

```
\node {\tikz\draw[step=.2cm] (0, 0) grid (.6, .2); \tikz\fill (0,0) rectangle (.4,.2)}
    child {node {\tikz\draw[step=.2cm] (0, 0) grid (.6, .2);}
    child {node {\tikz\draw[step=.2cm] (0, 0) grid (.6, .2);};
```

It outputs this:

[image]

How can I get the rectangle to fill inside the grid?

Comment: This nests `tikzpicture`s, which is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach nests `tikzpicture`s, which is not supported. Rather, you an use the `path picture` of nodes to draw the grid. Also, I recommend `forest` for drawing trees (yet the `grid` node style defined below works in plain Ti*k*Z as well, of course).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{grid/.style args={#1/#2}{draw,minimum height=1ex,minimum width=#1*1ex,
path picture={\foreach \XX in {1,...,\the\numexpr#1-1}
{\draw ([xshift=\XX*1ex]path picture bounding box.south west) --
([xshift=\XX*1ex]path picture bounding box.north west);
 }
\ifnum#2>0 
\foreach \XX in {1,...,#2}
{\fill ([xshift=1ex-\XX*1ex]path picture bounding box.south east) rectangle
([xshift=-\XX*1ex]path picture bounding box.north east);
 }
\fi  
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[,grid=5/2,
 [,grid=3/0]
 [,grid=3/0]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]